# Writing to QTcpSocket does not always emit readyRead signal on opposite QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I have been stuck on this for the past 5 days, I have **no** idea how to proceed.

**Overview:**

I have a `client UI` which interacts with a `data handler` library, and the `data handler` library utilizes a `network manager` library, which is where my problem lies.

**More Info**

Firstly, QT provides a basic example for interactions between a `QTcpServer` ([Fortune Server](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html))and a `QTcpSocket` ([Fortune Client](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html)).

I thus implemented this code into an extremely basic example of my own, which works like a charm and has no issues.

My own adaption of fortune [client](http://pastebin.com/uYvbFqVy) and [server](http://pastebin.com/CDzTVihJ) for the record (basic)

**Quick Explaination:**

Server application runs, click on `start server`, then on the client side, enter text in field and click `connect to server` and text is displayed, easy!

**Problem:**

Implementing the code above into my `network manager` library, does not fire the [`QTcpSocket::readyRead()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) in the server application above.

It connects to the `server`, where the [`QTcpServer::newConnection()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#newConnection) is fired, as expected, straight after which the `client` writes to the socket but the `readyRead()` on the server socket does not fire, however in the example given it does.

**Note:**
The same `port` and `ip address` is used in this `server-client` application example and my current application, and the server is also running.

**Further Information:**

From the above code, I copied over **directly** from the client. Only 2 things were changed/modified:

- String that is sent to server
- return types for method

This was copied into my `network mannager ::write()` method. When running my application, and instance of `QMainWindow` is passed via `data handler` class and creates an instance of my `network manager` class which inherits `QObject` and implements the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

**Code Examples:**

//`client_UI` Class (snippet):

```
data_mananger *dman = new data_mananger(this);                //this -> QMainWindow
ReturnObject r = dman->NET_AuthenticateUser_GetToken(Query);
```

//`data_manager` library (snippet)

```
data_mananger::data_mananger(QObject *_parent) :
    parent(_parent)
{}

ReturnObject data_mananger::NET_AuthenticateUser_GetToken(QString Query){
    //Query like "AUTH;U=xyz@a;P=1234"

    //convert query string to char
        QByteArray ba = Query.toLatin1();

    //send query and get QList return
        ReturnCode rCode = networkManager.write(ba);

    //...
}
```

//`netman` library (snippet)

```
//.h

class NETMANSHARED_EXPORT netman : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public
    netman();
    netman(QObject *_parent);
    //...

private:
    QTcpSocket *tcp_con;
    //...
};
```

//cpp

```
netman::netman(QObject *_parent) :
    parent(_parent)
{
    tcp_con = new QTcpSocket(parent);
}

        return;
    }
    serverIP.setAddress(serverInfo.addresses().first().toIPv4Address());
}

ReturnCode netman::write(QByteArray message, int portNumber){

    tcp_con->connectToHost(QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"), 5000);

    if (!tcp_con->waitForConnected())
    {
        qDebug(log_lib_netman_err) << "Unable to connect to server";
        return ReturnCode::FailedConnecting;
    }

    if (!tcp_con->isValid()) {
        qDebug(log_lib_netman_err) << "tcp socket invalid";
        return ReturnCode::SocketError;
    }

    if (!tcp_con->isOpen()) {
        qDebug(log_lib_netman_err) << "tcp socket not open";
        return ReturnCode::SocketError;
    }

    //    QByteArray block(message);
    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);

    out << QString("Hello world");

    if (!tcp_con->write(block)){
        qDebug(log_lib_netman_err) << "Unable to send data to server";
        return ReturnCode::WriteFailed;
    }
    else{
        qDebug(log_lib_netman_info) << "Data block sent";
        return ReturnCode::SentSuccess;
    }
}
```

**Conclusion:**

The core code of the client side has been fully implemented, yet I cannot see why this error occurs.

I would very much appreciate help/advice!

Comment: one observation: you definitely don't want to `connectToHost` every time you write. That function can take a long time to return, even if you're already connected or in the process of connecting.

Comment: have you tried flushing the socket?

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus thanks for that, however I am not close to finishing with my network manager library. But the issue that is holding me back is this mentioned above. I will keep your suggestion in mind when finishing my library

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus why should I flush if I use the "exact" same implementation as that in the server client demo?

Comment: I'll make up a good explanation to that if it fixes the immediate problem ;) Problems with the program flow/event loop can sometimes cause side effects like this. That said, just because you don't get `readyRead` doesn't mean the message isn't transmitted. I can't diff your code from the fortune example right now because my proxy won't let me access the code on pastebin.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus well...well...well It works. Now please give me, at the very least, a lecture on 1. why this works 2. how it works 3. how I was supposed to know that ;) Thank you very much. Might I add, adding the flush() feels like a hack of sorts, is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `tcp_con->flush()` statement to the end of your write function.

### Why/how this works

You weren't getting a `readyRead` signal in your receiver because the written data was being buffered into the socket but not actually transmitted 'over the wire'. The `flush()` command causes the buffer to be transmitted. From [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#flush)

> This function writes as much as possible from the internal write
>   buffer to the underlying network socket, without blocking. If any data
>   was written, this function returns true; otherwise false is returned.

### How are you supposed to know

In my case a lot of experience/frustration with serial ports and flushing. It's the equivalent of "have you rebooted it?" in the socket debugging toolbox.

If everything else is working fine, you may not have to `flush`, but it's kind of application specific and depends on the lifetime of the socket, the TCP window size, socket option settings, and various other factors. That said, I always flush because I like having complete control over my sockets, and I want to make sure data is transmitted when I want it to be. I don't think it's a hack, but in some cases it could be indicative of some other problem. Again, application specific.

### Why might the buffer not be flushing itself?

I'm pretty sure no flush is needed in the fortune server example because they `disconnectFromHost` at the end of the `sendFortune()` function, and from the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#disconnectFromHost):

> Attempts to close the socket. If there is pending data waiting to be
>   written, QAbstractSocket will enter ClosingState and wait until all
>   data has been written.

The socket would disconnect if it were destroyed as well, but from what I can see of your code you aren't doing that either, and the buffer isn't full, so probably nothing is actually stimulating the buffer to flush itself.

Other causes can be:

- flow control isn't returned to the event loop (blocking calls, etc), so the buffer flush is never performed.
- Transmit is occuring inside of a loop, which seems like it will exit (e.g. `while(dataToTransmit)`), but in fact the condition never becomes false, which leads to the event loop being blocked.
- Nagles algorithm: the buffer may be waiting for *more data* before it flushes itself to keep network throughput high. You can disable this by setting the `QAbstractSocket::LowDelayOption`, but it may adversely affect your throughput... it's normally used for latency-sensative applications.